# How to add Zoom & Pan option to anyChart SeatMap?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, anychart

We are using the anyChart SeatMap to render a SVG based seatmap in our IONIC application. But some of the seatmaps are large and we need to support zoom & pan options. I have tried exploring the 'Move & Zoom' options in anychart documentation but I think those work only with Maps. Even Scrollers do not seem to work.

Is there a way to add zoom & pan to SeatMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to implement using the library API. For details, check [the sample from the gallery](https://playground.anychart.com/gallery/src/Seat_Maps/Boeing_737).

Comment: Thanks, as a follow-up question considering the SVG, is being refreshed to capture bookings done by others and a person has zoomed & paned to a certain position, how to gracefully update the SVG without throwing the user out of the experience. For Zoom I am able to store the zoom state and use it along with update, but how to keep the context of pan?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to store the previous pan position with the current event system.

Comment: Ok. So as an alternative how to update the SVG data without having to reload/redraw the entire thing. Basically to support people booking from different places each view needs to be refreshed every X seconds. Now the experience is bad since the SVG resets since it is redrawn. But if we could just update the data then remembering the pan is not needed I assume.

Comment: You can override the series data on the fly without recreating the chart or reloading the page. For details, check the sample - https://playground.anychart.com/qcDViEsg